# How do I get email notifications for when someone answers my questions?

Tags: discussion, notifications, email

I posted a question but I have to sign in to see if someone answered it.

How do I set up email notifications of responses to a question I asked on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This question ought to be asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (that said, it is a reasonable question - I did not cast the down vote).

Comment: My next question was going to be what is the difference between stack exchange and stackoverflow?? Sorry, I've just really started using my account now. I see the stackexchange icon at the top left.. how is this connected with stackoverflow?

Comment: Stack Exchange is a network of question and answer sites on various topics, of which Stack Overflow is just one. Use the [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) site to ask/answer questions relating to the sites themselves (i.e. questions that do not relate to the intended discussion topics of the site).

Comment: Look at the "Email Settings" options in the left sidebar on your profile page.  I think "Inbox" is the one you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You visit your profile, and then visit preferences, and then [manage your Email-Settings/Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current), in the "Your Communities" section:

> [image]

Comment: I've selected the send me an email every three hours.. is there no way to send me an email whenever I get a respond?

Comment: I think the answer below to install the StackExchange app on an Android phone would be the best answer for certain users. I posted a feature-request to enable instantaneous e-mail notifications at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273333/can-we-have-instantaneous-e-mail-notifications

Comment: FYI the feature was already declined at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions

Answer (score 6):

You will automatically be notified of the following events to your question:

- an answer
- a comment
- a 'substantial edit'

This will arrive in your global inbox (shown in the top-right corner).

If you want to be notified by email of any inbox items, this can be done in your preferences:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current
```

These can be configured to be sent every 3 hours:

> [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to have been removed from the store
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385599/stack-overflow-mobile-app-removed-from-ios-app-store

Answer (score 3):

### These apps have been abandoned and are no longer available.

<strike>You can download and install the **[Stack Overflow iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808?mt=8)** or the **[Stack Exchange Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en_US)** on your phone. You will get easy notifications.</strike>

Comment: That't nice for people who have an Android/iPhone and can use the app but that is not always the case.

Comment: Answer presumes one has an 'app' capable phone. (-1)