# I have never received emails about my posts

Tags: support, notifications, email

I have never received emails about my posts despite my email settings being OK as far as I can tell.

I have had emails from Stack Overflow unrelated to my posts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you mark the *Send me new responses to my posts via email* checkbox on each post when you posted?

Comment: No - I have never seen this box - where is it? - Just tried a new question here and could not see it - Is there a global setting for this like most other sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email notifications in stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/email-notifications-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Not quite @gnat that post is missing that you need to tick the box on every question, isn't it?

Comment: I cannot find that box on my Safari - does it appear as soon as a question form is opened or later? It does not appear to be in the source code

Comment: @rene after closer compare of what's in there with this question, you seem to have a point (retracted my dupe vote)

Comment: I don't see that checkbox in chrome, the only one I see is to self answer the question you are posting.

Comment: @Joe if you don't get the checkbox shown in my answer feel free to post a bug report with screenshots and used browser.

Comment: I thought reporting a bug was my original purpose ??? -

Comment: @NevilleHillyer well, we figured out that the checkbox is there (or not) by design. Now back to your problem: Your email address on [preferences](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) is correct and you did mark *Email me my unread inbox messages* and set it to daily/weekly/3hours? No email in your spam folder by accident?

Comment: Do you have an example of a reply you would have expected to receive by email? From your recent activity, it looks like you've replied to comments within an hour or two, and your email preferences are set to send you unread notifications every 3 hours. If you read your inbox messages here on the site or via an SE mobile app within 3 hours (whatever your frequency settings are for email notifications), there's nothing to email you about.

Comment: I received my first ever 'three hourly" email @ 20.59 GMT - a lot more than 3 hours after posts!! - I assume an admin has fixed something - if so thanks - the missing tick box for some of us still needs fixing

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned this before: "That checkbox is only be shown if the user has not opted into receiving unread inbox messages via email." - Very silly system - I prefer Apple forums

Comment: I am fully upvoting this question, yes!!! email NEVER WORK, I turned every single settings ON, but 3 years passed, never received a single email coming from stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

On the initial posting of your question or answer you'll find just above the button that you have to click before you can post your question or answer there is a checkbox that states

> Send me new responses to my posts via email

[image]

You can't subscribe to email updates once it is posted. The checkbox isn't shown in that case.
Checking it will send you an email if comments or edits are made to your post.

**If you don't get that checkbox you have selected `"email me my unread inbox messages"` in your [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250749/158100)**

You get notification also in your inbox, at the top of the screen:

[image]

If you read the inbox notifications within the timelimit you choose in your email-preferences **NO** e-mail will be send because at that moment the notification is no longer un-read.

You can check this post to manage your [email settings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/email-notifications-in-stackoverflow).

Comment: Is there something you need to do to get that checkbox to show up? The only one I see when asking a question is a check box to self answer the question at the same time you post it.

Comment: I created a new account to verify this. Notice that you can only do this on initial post, not on an edit. I have the same functionality on Chrome. The self-answer checkbox is **below** the post button, the checkbox for the email is **above** it.

Comment: I clicked on the ask a question button and the checkbox did not show up for me. I tried this on stackoverflow, meta stackoverflow and meta stackexchange with no luck.

Comment: @JoeW in that case feel free to post a bug

Comment: I posted a bug on meta stackexhcange.

Comment: I thought that was the purpose of this thread !!

Comment: @NevilleHillyer I don't think so. You asked a support question, that is now answered as several users confirm this works. Turns out for some users this doesn't work. That is a bug and needs developer attention and as such a new post. But no worries it is already posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250746/receive-emails-for-responses-to-posts)

Comment: @NevilleHillyer what are your [email settings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/email-notifications-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Did you enter an e-mail address in your profile?

Comment: Confirming that I also don't see the checkbox, and I do have an email set in my notification preferences. I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on Windows 7.

Comment: @sphanley in that case you must have selected "email me my unread inbox messages" in your profile which is basically the same setting.

Comment: Sure enough, unchecking that (which I didn't want on to begin with) causes the checkbox on the question page to reappear.

Answer (score 4):

As answered on meta stackexchange the checkbox to send responses via email will not show up if you have your email preferences set up to send you notifications of unread items in your in box. ([Receive emails for responses to posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250746/receive-emails-for-responses-to-posts/250749#250749)) I would check your email settings to make sure it is all setup correctly and remember that it will only send an email if it has not been checked by you when it comes time to send the email.

Answer (score 3):

To receive emails on your posts, you need to click the check box under each question labeled: "Send me new responses to my posts via email"

[image: Check Box to check]

The same option exists under each answer you post.

Comment: You beat me to it...

Comment: Should I see it here? I have yet to find it.

Comment: @NevilleHillyer You can only check this  box when the post is created, not on an edit.

Comment: It does not work for everybody - please accept that this is a long standing serious bug

Comment: @ Andy we have been told that the box should also be available for answers - it never is for me - I have tried new questions (without posting them) but the box is not there for me

Comment: Very silly system:  "That checkbox is only be shown if the user has not opted into receiving unread inbox messages via email."