# How do I get Stack Overflow to send me new answers (or alerts) through email?

Tags: support, notifications, email

How I can customise my account for it to send me email notifications and alerts of new answers and comments?

I'm fairly new, is there a help page that describes this?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/email-notifications-in-stackoverflow ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a social media site where we get emails on everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange already has that. Simply go to your [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), and enter in an email:

[image]

At the end of the day, anything unread pops up:

[image]

Comment: My pencil is too thick, let me sharpen it :P

Comment: Does that also mail you answers?

Comment: @Henry it should also mail you answers, because they go in your inbox.