# Stack Overflow Mobile app removed from iOS App Store?

Tags: support, ios-app

I just realised the Stack Overflow app was offloaded from my iPhone so I went to re-download it. However it hit me with a notification saying it couldn’t as the app was no longer on the App Store. Wanting to see if this was true, I searched up Stack Overflow on the App Store and, sure enough, it wasn’t there.

I wanted to ask, was this on purpose and why? Because the Stack Exchange app is still there. Or is there a problem with my device?

Comment: Probably related: [What happened to the Stack Overflow app for Android?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373307/7795130)

Comment: Oh...didn’t realise that. I definitely remember it being around earlier this month though...then again knowing myself I have no sense of time.

Comment: offloaded? you mean they deleted the app from your phone without your consent?

Comment: @JeshanBabooa "offloading" on iOS is a feature you can turn on to save disk space. If an app isn't used in a long time, it will be removed from your device. Your data for the app will still be kept, and the icon will stay on the home screen. The next time you try to launch the app it will first download it again, and then launch it.

Comment: This situation raises an unfortunate gotcha of automatic offloading and is why I keep it disabled.  There's no way for OP to regain the current Stack Overflow app now even though the app is still functional today.  I've seen this scenario play out with several outdated but still useful apps.  I wish Apple would be more explicit here.

Comment: Too bad. The app was kind of crappy, but it worked and I received notifications through it. I just changed phones and the app carried across through the backup/restore. I only noticed something was wrong when Login With Facebook said the app was still in test mode. Solving that led me here (only 2 years and 4 months later).

Answer (score 50):

We didn't deliberately de-list, but some issues in both the App Store and Marketplace require us to submit a new version prior to re-listing. The reasons were simple nuisance things that creep up that didn't have much to do with the app *per se* — like robot trademark infringement complaints — but since we're not actively working on the app, they just collected.

We don't honestly know what our native app strategy is going to look like in the next couple of years. We've invested heavily in a fully responsive information architecture that's starting to bear fruit, and we're now doing a lot of user satisfaction research to find out what's missing for folks on smaller screens and in the context of being mobile.

For now, pushing a new version *just* to get the apps re-listed without being able to put a serious investment in anything but critical bug fixes just doesn't seem like the right turn to take. We know some folks were still using the app to make the most of notifications, but we don't just want to get it back in circulation for the sake of that without being able to really resource it properly.

As / if this changes, we'll let folks know. But for now, there are no plans to reinvest in *native* apps as the best strategy for meeting user's needs for small devices and in mobile settings. I'm sad to say it, but it's better to just be deliberate about not supporting it at this juncture than trying to keep it going half-efforted for a little while longer.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that does make sense. Welp, guess no push notifications of if my answer gets questioned for me. I understand though.

Comment: @Eleeza There is still the general SE app, which works great :)

Comment: Yeah, I could use that. (I just realised I typed "if someone questions my answer" instead of "if someone answers my question" haha)

Comment: If push notifications are what the people want (as of now) then is https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/ feasible? Mobile browsers seem to keep adopting app-like behavior so I think that native apps should always be a last resort. If YouTube and all those blogs and recipe sites want to send me notifications then why not Stack Exchange?

Comment: Maybe fixing bugs in the Stack Exchange app is a good strategy? Not only does it show a blank white screen after you comment or answer on iOS 12, which renders the app basically unusable, there's [a bug with the code view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287914/code-view-issues-are-still-here), which has been there for _2 and a half years_ now and which doesn't let people read long code because it's getting cut off.

Comment: Could that explain why JavaScript devs get paid twice more than native mobile (Swift/Java) devs in my company?

Comment: I will be honest...the fully responsive site still doesnt work as nice as a native app on the phone.  I'd like you guys to reconsider as I hate browsing SO via the web on my mobile phone.  The SE app is much better...

Comment: "pushing a new version just to get the apps re-listed without being able to put a serious investment in anything but critical bug fixes just doesn't seem like the right turn to take" Why not? You maximize your impact with little effort. To me it seems like the low hanging fruit.

Comment: @TimPost if you open-source the app, you would get more than just the critical bugs being fixed.

Comment: @Cœur That still requires someone on our side, and we haven't backfilled the role of mobile developer (and not sure if we're going to for some time). If someone from the company can't hold the metaphorical keys to the kingdom (as in getting new versions out, ensuring our infosec people are appropriately looped in, etc) - we'd just be headed right back to the same predicament we're in. The burden is more than a company should feel comfortable asking volunteer contributors, because the accountability is just way too high.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, the Stack Exchange app still exists on iOS but it shows as being last updated 2 years ago so I'm not sure this is a solution.  Who knows if that one will be delisted tomorrow?  At least the web apps are really good on mobile.  The only feature I'm missing are the notifications.

Comment: Shame on you SO, such a big company that passes on mobile apps for such a dumb issue, and don’t tell us you’re not actively maintaining the mobile apps that’s more scary.

Comment: Just open source it, there is not / can’t be a single iOS app developer across the entirety of Stack Overflow?! The irony.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary please read [the answer from SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348112/241919) as to why the app couldn't be open-sourced.