# Are the Stack Overflow native apps supported by Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-app

While we have a couple questions which obliquely answer this question, I believe it would be nice to have a canonical Meta Stack Overflow Q&A to which to point users when asked for support for the Stack Overflow mobile app (iOS or Android).

Related, but not quite duplicate:

- [What happened to the Stack Overflow app for Android?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android)
  (asks a different question about why the app left the Google Play Store, and does not have an answer from the company, although [animuson♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson), an employee, did edit [one of the answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379742/215552); which does not carry any binding support)
- [Stack Overflow Mobile app removed from iOS App Store?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385599/stack-overflow-mobile-app-removed-from-ios-app-store) (asks a similar question to the above, on the Apple App Store side. [This was answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385622/215552) by [Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post), an employee of Stack Overflow. However, the answer is not definitive, saying:

  > As / if this changes, we'll let folks know. But for now, there are no plans to reinvest in native apps as the best strategy for meeting user's needs for small devices and in mobile settings. I'm sad to say it, but it's better to just be deliberate about not supporting it at this juncture than trying to keep it going half-efforted for a little while longer.

If we can take that answer as meaning no support for any native app (iOS or Android), we can close this question, and other [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions regarding the apps as duplicates of that one.

If not, I'm still looking for an answer (preferably from an employee) that will help users of the mobile apps decide whether to expect support for bugs in the apps or not.

Comment: FWIW for Android, the Stack Overflow app was taken down earlier than the Stack Exchange app, but both apps have been taken down from the Play Store. Anyway, [this is the canonical FAQ on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/241919)

Comment: Animuson also edited the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/154798/revisions) (rev21) adding that the apple app store app is no longer available and only server side bugs will be fixed, not client (app) side, I'd say that's pretty definitive. Yaakov too has said [no more development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/684990)

Comment: So, maybe we need a copy of that answer here on MSO...

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessary [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android) has been working fine as a canonical.

Comment: That said, it'd be helpful if OP accepted the abandonment answer and if the commentary to use the SE app instead were removed

Comment: There’s no shortage of evidence that the apps aren’t being developed right now and probably won’t be in the near future. But I still use the SE iOS app and I find it helpful to continue to accept questions on it: many questions are proper duplicates and the community has been able to find workarounds for some of the bugs out there.

Comment: @Laurel Evidence, sure, but I'm looking for something canonical on MSO. And the fact that it still takes 5 votes to close on MSO should leave plenty of time for the community to find workarounds, or vote for other duplicates. And of course gold badge holders and others can edit the list of duplicates as they see fit. Finally, this question is just about the SO app, not the SE app (which I would relegate to MSE).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they're no longer supported, and [the infrastructure for them was decommissioned in late 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/165261).

Our focus on mobile entails continued investment in our responsive information architecture, with the eventual plan of looking into bringing remaining much loved app-exclusive features to the web.

With new projects being built with responsive requirements in mind, we'll also eventually embark on a tech debt project to also deprecate the mobile views.

I don't have a timeline for this (and I'm not promising features); I'm just letting folks know what the horizon looks like. When I wrote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385622/215552), there was still a little speculation, but that's long since been settled.

Comment: What "app-exclusive features" are there? The only one I was aware of was the ability to send push notifications to your device. Are there others?

Comment: @CodyGray The main one I can think of is precisely that, but I know I've seen others mentioned so I left the plurality just to be sure I didn't frighten anyone :) When the time comes the team will do a full audit so, we'll know for certain.