# Where do I send bug reports to Stack Overflow about the Stack Overflow app?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-app, avatar

I just signed up to a new account because my old one is connected with Google who have dropped support for my favourite email client, and it’s simply easier to live without Google now.

On signing up again, I noticed a small bug (details follow) and wondered how I send a bug report to Stack Overflow about Stack Overflow. I couldn't find the mechanism anywhere appropriate so I thought I would write this and see if a moderator will pick it up and pass it on.

The Bug:

When you first log in, it asks you to pick an identipic (or something to that effect) which is the profile picture for a user on the site. Instead of going with the arbitrary identipic (what’s-it-called), I chose to upload the logo from my company instead.

On getting past the getting started bit and arriving at the main page where it shows my identipic (thingamajig) instead of my company logo, it shows the arbitrary identipic (which I am sure I will be able to change on my profile now I am logged in, but I don't think that was the behaviour intended by the developer.)

Signing up to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can also just remove the Google integration from your old account (go to your account and then "Logins")

Comment: The [mobile app infrastructure is being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/15168).  There is no point in sending bug reports other than to the bit-bucket in the sky (`/dev/null` on Unix-like systems).  In August 2020, the question [Are the Stack Overflow native apps still supported by Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400392/15168) got the answer "No", so this has been pending for several years.

Comment: what’s-it-called and thingamajig -> identicon. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated) for more

Answer (score 17):

If you mean the mobile app, nowhere; start using the website instead. The mobile app infrastructure [has been axed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/332043). Anything that may still work at this point is subject to breaking at any point by now. As an aside, the apps aren't maintained, and haven't been for ages. The infrastructure being axed is just that being formally acknowledged.

If you just mean the website, you're in the right place. Meta is [the place for general bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) about Stack Overflow.

Comment: While I understand this I must say I actually preferred the Mobile App design to the Media Query Website, the websites on phone just look a little to cluttered :(