# The Stack Overflow app appears to have broken on iOS 14 - is there a plan to fix this?

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

The Stack Overflow app appears to have broken on iOS 14 - is there a plan to fix this?

(Perhaps the elephant in the room is that there is some reason this app is no longer supported, but this is not documented?)

Comment: I fear there won't be a plan, because the app is no longer supported. Sorry.

Comment: See [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/289905).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that's what this post is asking for - some sort of official source on this. Right now, the closest I can find is [an answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385599/stack-overflow-mobile-app-removed-from-ios-app-store). While it *does* come from an official source, I don't think it counts for making people aware of the support status of the app.

Comment: You mean like [the one in the tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming/300389#300389)?

Comment: That said, _sometimes_ a fix is simple enough, like renewing a certificate somewhere, and we get to use the app a little longer. But it'll never be more than a stopgap measure.

Comment: @VLAZ Unlike Stack *Exchange* app, [SE has officially declared that the Stack *Overflow* app should be gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use/154798?noredirect=1#comment1180254_154798).

Comment: Have you tried the Stack Exchange app instead? What type of iPhone are you using? The update to iOS 14 didn’t cause any more issues on the SE app for me or several other people.

Comment: The elephant in the room is [the November 2017 mass layoff](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678) (that included *all* working on the mobile applications, both Android and iOS)

Comment: I know we're all thinking it, how sort of pathetic it is that of all the social platforms there are, the one that is the home de facto to the world's greatest software developers completely flopped the whole mobile app thing.

Answer (score 14):

From the [canonical CW answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076/158100) on MSE:

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

And that reflects the comments on the question from [Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403139/the-stackoverflow-app-appears-to-have-broken-on-ios-14-is-there-a-plan-to-fix#comment810367_403139) as well:

> I fear there won't be a plan, because the app is no longer supported.
> That said, sometimes a fix is simple enough, like renewing a certificate somewhere, and we get to use the app a little longer. But it'll never be more than a stopgap measure.

No plan, no future, no 6 to 8 weeks.