Should all questions with the [ios-app] tag on MSO be closed as the app has been dead for years?
Just over seven years ago, I asked a question on MSO about the misbehaviour of the iOS app for Stack Overflow (tag on MSO ios-app — question iOS app does not show the previous edit message when re-editing during grace period).  Earlier today, it was closed as "off-topic" — something which doesn't bother me as questions about the iOS app are pointless now since the app has been defunct for years.
There are 114 questions with the tag (plus this one), many of which (about 83 of them) are not closed.
Question: is it worth putting forth an effort to close the remaining unclosed questions?

Never close a question, it's important for AI to have something to show users (it doesn't care if it's no longer relevant).

Having this done, getting a notification on the site and then an email telling me "your question has been closed ... here's an empty placeholder for where feedback would be"... I'd forgotten the app was even a thing. :D

@PoulBak closed questions are still visible.

@TylerH: Yeah, I was actually being sarcastic (should have mentioned),

@TylerH But the banner says you must not look, does it not?

Yes, they should be closed
In almost all cases, yes, those should be closed as:

Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete.

There will be some questions which are still relevant and shouldn't be closed, depending on what the question is actually asking. Each question needs to be read and evaluated, rather than unconditionally closed, just because it has that tag. For example, this current question shouldn't be closed for that reason, but does have the ios-app tag.  Nor should this question describing an issue that occurred on both the website and the Android app be closed (unless it no longer occurs on the website, either).
Is it worth the effort?
Probably, but it's definitely a low priority.
Tags for legacy Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow initiatives/system changes
The tag discussed in this question is not the only one for which such closures are appropriate. There are also at least the following tags for which the bulk of the questions should be closed for the same reason (and similarly evaluated for ones which remain relevant):



Tag
FilteredClose-voteQueue
UnclosedQuestionSearch
UnclosedCount




ios-app
CV queue
search
1


android-app
CV queue
search
0


stack-overflow-app
CV queue
search
0


developer-story
CV queue
search
2


legacy-stack-overflow-jobs
CV queue
search
0


legacy-stack-overflow-jobs-messages
CV queue
search
0


mobile-web
CV queue
search
0


new-nav
CV queue
search
1



If you want to participate in closing these, I recommend going through the Close-vote Review Queue first, as doing so will help keep close-votes concentrated on individual questions, so the questions actually get closed. If there are no more questions for you to review for closure, then going through a search for those that are not yet closed will put more in the Close-vote Review Queue for other users to review.

Thank you!  Should I simply go through the questions and VTC those that meet your criteria, and trust that other people will also VTC the questions?  Or do we need to wait until we get to a 'burnination' stage, though eliminating the tag isn't what is requested — it had meaning at one time and the questions form a part of the history of MSO?  Maybe what I'm seeking is a "closeting" for the questions — putting them in the closet by closing them.

@JonathanLeffler As long as people are actually reading the questions and not voting to close the relatively rare ones which are still relevant (e.g., when the question is also about something that's still in the main site, not just the legacy technology/system feature), then I don't have a problem with people voting to close them, either by visiting the questions or in the close-vote review queue. The thing that's not permitted is editing questions in response to a burnination post without the burnination being approved through the process.

Oh flip!  There's a limit on how many close votes you can do in a day.  I just reached it.

I went through a period where I was hitting it daily. I don't recommend it. There are way more effective ways to help build and curate a useful Q&A resource - such as moving to a new one.

@JonathanLeffler In general, I'd suggest first visiting the close-vote review queue and doing as many reviews in there as you can. Working the review queue first keeps your and other people's close-votes consolidated on the same questions, so the questions actually get closed, when appropriate, rather than having questions without enough close votes to close them. Once there aren't any more for you to review in the close-vote review queue, then casting close-votes from searches will help put more into the review queue for others to review.

@Makyen: okay — message received. I've not frequented the close vote review queue. Is it normally nearly empty?  I'll find out soon enough, but if the review queue is more than about 10 entries long, I likely wouldn't do much; I would not be achieving my main purpose.

@JonathanLeffler The MSO close-vote queue is indeed usually nearly empty, with the length resulting from these being close-voted being highly unusual. I just went through it a few minutes ago, so at the moment, it's nearly empty again (and my count of close-vote reviews on MSO increased by over 40%).

Should this closure exclude, for example [status-completed] questions regarding the apps?

@RyanM I don't see any reason to exclude those. "Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete" is still accurate as a close reason and no further answers are reasonable.

The review queue was empty, so I went to your search list and VTC'd a bunch of questions.

@Makyen While I agree w/ you that such questions should be closed for the prescribed reason description, I feel questions tagged [status-completed] already/inherently don't warrant further answers :-)

"For example, this current question shouldn't be closed for that reason, but does have the ios-app tag." I disagree w/ this one. Perhaps in 2019 that question was relevant, but it's now been 5 years since it was last on the App Store. Anyone who even still has an iPhone in use from 2019 that ever had the app on their phone has surely long since removed the app or become aware that it is no longer supported. It hasn't even been developed since 2015, nearly 10 years ago.

@TylerH I believe you've misunderstood the meaning of "this current question".  It refers to the question that you are looking at right now (note the target of the link).

@RyanM Oops, yes. I saw that it was grey for me and thought it was the one I was thinking of: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385599/stack-overflow-mobile-app-removed-from-ios-app-store

Update: As of July 22nd, all [legacy-stack-overflow-jobs] questions have been closed. We're very close with [ios-app], [android-app], and [stack-overflow-app].

@pigrammer the remaining [meta-tag:ios-app], [meta-tag:android-app], and [meta-tag:stack-overflow-app] questions you're looking at shouldn't be closed.

@AbdulAzizBarkat While this question shouldn't be closed, I think this one, with all three tags, should be, as the app it's asking to make open source no longer exists.

@pigrammer that question IMO has historical value and should be kept.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Closing the question is still keeping it. No one can do anything that contributes to the discussion by commenting on/answering that question.

@pigrammer it is a common request to ask to open-source no-longer-maintained projects.  Almost certainly, the source code still exists, and staff could respond there.  Alternatively, a community member might hypothetically decompile the apps and provide source code that way (copyright implications aside), possibly having asked permission from SE .

Is there a way to upgrade the 'search' links in the table so that it does not show questions I've already voted to close?

@JonathanLeffler no, search doesn't provide any way to filter on the basis of questions you've voted on.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: Bother.  Thanks for the information, even if it wasn't what I was hoping to hear.

@RyanM: I came across a question tagged both [meta-tag:mobile-web] and [meta-tag:winter-bash-2020].  Should questions with the Winter Bash tags be closed too, do you think?  As part of this exercise, or as another question?

@JonathanLeffler please read the questions that you're closing before casting a close vote. Several of your close votes are incorrect and are then further voted on blindly by other users causing incorrect closures. Some examples that I noticed today: 1, 2

@AbdulAzizBarkat: I mildly wondered about those two (and some others), but took the tags as controlling.  I'd be delighted if other people took some active interest in choosing the first close votes, rather than leaving it all to me.  Tag removal rather than question closure is, in many ways, a more serious decision.

@JonathanLeffler Tags are never controlling;  question content is.  Mis-tagging of questions is extremely common, as people don't always read the tag usage guidance (see, for example, the [api] tag on main, which has over 94,000 usages despite its usage guidance starting with "DO NOT USE."). You should always feel able to retag mis-tagged questions. Also, as Makyen's answer here notes: "Each question needs to be read and evaluated, rather than unconditionally closed, just because it has that tag." If the tags were controlling, we'd just script it.
